# Android OSM scroll map

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I am new at OSMdroid and I am currently trying to make an application. The problem is when I load the map (it's downloaded and stored in the cache) and zoom (by pinching or pressing the zoom button) the whole map doesn't refresh. It will only refresh the part where my screen is so if I scroll away it looks like this:

[image]

And after some scrolling and zooming in the whole map disappears. It will only come back when I zoom out.

Does some one know why this happends? I tried to do this:

```
mapView.get().setMapListener(new DelayedMapListener(new MapListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onZoom(ZoomEvent arg0) {
            mapView.get().getTileProvider().clearTileCache(); 
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent arg0) {

            return false;
        }
    },100));
```

But that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

You are zooming in beyond where you have offline tile imagery. So for example, you have tile imagery to level 17 and you are zooming in to level 18. The maps will scale zoom level 17 up to 18 for what is on the screen (in the cache) for visual effect when zooming, but it won't scale beyond that because it expects the regular tiles will be available.

Create an ITileSource with the appropriate zoom levels, or call setMaxZoomLevel() on the MapView.